# Is there a binary of Pipe Viewer (`pv`) for Windows?

Tags: windows, pv

I read about the Pipe Viewer (`pv`) Linux utility, and it sounds really useful. I use plenty of Linux tools on Windows, but this one doesn't seem to be part of the msysgit suite that I use.

How can I get a Windows binary of it?

Comment: I'm not certain if its a windows binary or if it's a cygwin compile job, but if you get no definite replies i'll ask the author for you on monday when i'm in work.

Comment: Thanks @Sirex ! I actually sent him a message about it in his contact form, and didn't get a reply yet.

Comment: cygwin compile apparently.

Answer (score 2):

I have stumbled over this question today, as I am looking the same kind of tool for Windows.
I didn't found one for Windows, but I found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504204/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-alternative-to-pipe-viewer-for-windows-platform#) answer from Stackoverflow, and the solution is just to use the one from Cygwin.

Here is the quote from there:

> I finally made it work on Cygwin environment though that is not answer for the original post. "--disable-nls" does the trick.
>
> ./configure --disable-nls
>
> make
>
> make test
>
> cp pv /usr/bin

Comment: Why not `make install`?

Answer (score 1):

It is already available as a cygwin package for 32 and 64 bits.

Pipeviewer for Cygwin 32 bits:

https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Fpv%2Fpv-1.4.4-1&grep=pv.exe
https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Fpv%2Fpv-1.4.12-1&grep=pv.exe

Pipeviewer for Cygwin 64 bits:

https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fpv%2Fpv-1.4.12-1&grep=pv.exe

Comment: How can I download this ? I see only a file listing on that page

Comment: @Radon8472 use cygwin setup.exe (32 or 64 bit) to install pv.

Comment: I already have cygwin, I only have to add pv, because it is not part of my current setup

Answer (score 0):

There is a new tool we built called [PipeViewer](https://github.com/cyberark/PipeViewer) for Windows.
It can list you all the named pipes on Windows with a detailed overview of named pipes.

Comment: Nice tool, but unfortunally it does not help with this question

Comment: Oh, you wanted the same `pv` for Linux as a Windows binary? if that's the case you are right.